# Windows 10 Development: Showing Message Dialog when phone's hardware button is pressed

Tags: c#, windows-10-mobile

I wish to display a message dialog on a page when the back button is pressed on that page.

I have already made the back button works as it should. So I am not including the full code that makes the back button work. What I need to is for the message dialog to show on the specific page (SomePage in this case).

I have this code in `App.xaml.cs` under the `OnBackRequested` event:

```
if (rootFrame.CanGoBack && rootFrame.SourcePageType.Name != "SomePage")
{
    MessageDialog errormessage = new MessageDialog("Something");

    errormessage.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Some Option", new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.CommandInvokedHandler)));
    errormessage.ShowAsync();
}
private void _CommandInvokedHandler(IUICommand command)
{
    Frame aFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    if (command.Label == "Some Option")
    {
        aFrame.GoBack();
    }

}
```

So after debugging line by line, `System.ArgumentException` in my application is written in the debugging console when the `ShowAsync()` function is triggered. I think I cannot call `ShowAsync()` on `App.xaml.cs` to show on `SomePage` but maybe I must call it on `SomePage`. I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: ShowAsync works fine in App.xaml.cs for me. Can you please share full code after all?

Comment: Considering that from SomePage you can only navigate backwards, you could also use an OnNavigatingFrom handler. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227509. My point would be to implement your logic, "closer" to your page, and not in App.xaml.cs file. The OnNavigatingFrom has to be implemented in SomePage.cs